# Unable to hookup Jprofiler on a WAS JVM

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1, jprofiler

We are unable to instrument the jprofiler on the Webshpere App server JVM.
We are getting errors like below

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com/jprofiler/agent/Agent.registerAnnotationMethods([[Ljava/lang/String;[I[II)V
        at com.jprofiler.agent.Agent.registerInterceptions(ejt:579)
        at com.jprofiler.agent.Agent.registerAllAnnotationMethods(ejt:513)
        at com.jprofiler.agent.Agent.<clinit>(ejt:149)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:194)
```

when i start the JVM, the JVM was able to communicate to the jprofiler client. and i was able to see some samples before the JVM starts. and after a few sec the JVM crashes and it is in stopped status.

Environment details
App server - WAS 6.1
java version "1.5.0_55"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_55-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 1.5.0_55-b10, mixed mode)

i see this in the log

```
JProfiler> Protocol version 37
JProfiler> Using JVMTI
JProfiler> Thread status info workaround enabled.
JProfiler> 32-bit library
JProfiler> Listening on port: 8849.
JProfiler> Native library initialized
JProfiler> VM initialized
JProfiler> Waiting for a connection from the JProfiler GUI ...
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com/jprofiler/agent/Agent.registerAnnotationMeth
ods([[Ljava/lang/String;[I[II)V
        at com.jprofiler.agent.Agent.registerInterceptions(ejt:579)
        at com.jprofiler.agent.Agent.registerAllAnnotationMethods(ejt:513)
        at com.jprofiler.agent.Agent.<clinit>(ejt:149)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:194)
JProfiler> Using dynamic instrumentation
JProfiler> Time measurement: elapsed time
JProfiler> CPU profiling enabled
```

and the JVM is in stopped status. If i remove the argument from "Generic JVM arguments" i'm able to start the JVM without jprofiler.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have an agent.jar from a different
JProfiler version in your bootclasspath or classpath. Please check your system for
any different JProfiler version to avoid this.